# Good "Too Localized Example" for FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

I think it'd be good to have a couple of solid examples of what is "Too Localized" for our FAQ.  Respond below.

Answer (score 10):

I'm walking on Dartmoor this weekend, is the weather likely to be ok?

Comment: The really bad thing is that in my tired state when I wrote it, I almost put it as an actual question on the site rather than here!

Answer (score 8):

Will start with one:

"When will the [insert section] of the Bartram Trail be repaired?"

Answer (score 3):

Why has someone left their rucksack on the top of High Willhays?